# How to iterate over class methods

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I import a module and I want to iterate over the static methods therein, is there a way to do that?

In the module:

```
class duck():
    @staticmethod
    def duck_quack():            
        return 'Quacks like a duck'
    @staticmethod
    def person_walk():            
        return 'Walks like a person'
```

In the controller:

```
from applications.... import duck

m = duck()

def result_m():
    for stuff in dir(m):
        if 'person' in stuff:
            result = stuff
        elif 'duck' in stuff:
            result = stuff
```

Instead, I keep getting a `None` response. Is there a better way than using this?

Comment: You need to actually *call* those methods to get the value returned - `if 'person' in stuff():`. But what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: sorry I misprinted the methods. What I want is to only print from the method with the 'keyword provided, in this case, either 'person', or 'duck'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting a None response because you are not returning anything. Methods that do not have a return statement return None.

I'm not sure what is the end goal of your approach, but I would do it thus:

```
obj = Duck()

def say_something(keyword):
     return getattr(obj, keyword, None)

print(say_something('duck')())
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @staticmethod
...     def duck():
...        return 'Quak!'
...     @staticmethod
...     def person():
...        return 'Hello'
...
>>> a = Foo()
>>> def say_something(thing):
...     return getattr(a, thing, None)
...
>>> print(say_something('duck')())
Quak!
>>> print(say_something('person')())
Hello
```

`getattr` will return `None` by default (here I am explicitly passing it in as the third argument). Since you can't call None, you'll get this as a result:

```
>>> print(say_something('Foo')())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

So its best if you store the result and check that its not `None`, or return some other callable:

```
>>> def say_something(thing):
...     return getattr(a, thing, lambda: 'Not Found')
...
>>> say_something('duck')()
'Quak!'
>>> say_something('person')()
'Hello'
>>> say_something('foo')()
'Not Found'
```

Comment: Why would you rely on scope for this? Why not `def say_something(obj, keyword):` (admittedly, this perhaps makes it even clearer that you're getting no benefit over calling `getattr` directly)?

Comment: No particular reason, except following the layout that the OP had in their post. Ideally one would have a Person class and Duck class and just call those individually rather than relying on an internal implementation (by getattr). Tomorrow if the method changes this code will break as well - whereas with the other approach the interface remains unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your function has several problems:

1. It doesn't take arguments, so you rely on scope for variable access;
2. It doesn't `return` anything; and
3. If both methods are present, which one is `result` last depends on the order of keys in the dictionary.

Try:

```
def result_m(m):
    for stuff in dir(m):
        if 'person' in stuff:
            result = stuff
        elif 'duck' in stuff:
            result = stuff
    return result
```

and consider making an argument for the word to search for.

Comment: can you call attributes with static methods?

Comment: like getattr(class, method)()?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out?

Comment: trust me I have done many options including the attr but nothing has worked..like getattr(m, stuff)

Comment: `>>> getattr(m, "person_walk")()` gives `'Walks like a person'`