# Calling another class function in a loop in current class

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, for-loop, iterator

I have 2 class Emoji and EmojiRun. 
I want to call Emoji class function through EmojiRun, using a infinite loop

```
class Emoji:
    def __init__(self):
        self.green = (0, 255, 0)
        self.yellow = (255, 255, 0)
        self.blue = (0, 0, 255)
        self.red = (255, 0, 0)
        self.white = (255, 255, 255)
        self.nothing = (0, 0, 0)
        self.brown = (165, 42, 42)

    def face(self):
        return face

    def smile(self):
        return smile

    def sad(self):
        return sad
```

In my EmojiRun class, I need to call function `face`, `smile`, `sad`.
I can call it individually, but I want to know if there is an way of iterate through Class Emoji's function, like the example below, I know its wrong

```
#Main class to run Emoji
from animatedEmoji import Emoji
from sense_hat import SenseHat
from time import sleep

#Class instance emoji
emoji = Emoji()
sense = SenseHat()

while True:
  #Forloop to call emoji functions 1 by 1
  for x in Emoji:
     sense.set_pixels(emoji.function[x])
     sleep(3)
```

Comment: You can have kind of factory function which returns `{ face: face(function face), smile: smile, sad: sad}` and then call this function which returns the dict, iterate over it and call the functions in a loop

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349080/how-to-iterate-over-class-methods help?

Comment: Why does your function `sad` return `sad`? It would help if your emoji class would at least compile, the current way requires guessing, which is always bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function that gives you all the expressions that an `Emoji` supports:

```
class Emoji:
    ... // same code as before
    def expressions(self):
        yield self.face
        yield self.smile
        yield self.sad
```

You could then call it with:

```
e = Emoji()
for exp in e.expressions():
    sense.set_pixels(exp())
    sleep(3)
```

Instead of providing bound memberfunctions, you could probably just as well invoke them and yield their results.

This approach works as long as there are just a handful of expressions. Once you have many of them, maintaining the `expressions()` function becomes cumbersome. Even more so when you have derived classes. In that case, I'd suggest you research two alternative approaches:

- Introspection. Basically, it means that you scan an object for methods that e.g. take no parameters (other than `self`) and return an expression. That probably requires return type annotations on the functions.
- Registering expressions. Read the documentation for decorators, which allow you to write one that maintains a list of expression functions for each type. All you have to do is to prefix the function declaration with a `@expression_function` then.

Answer (score 0):

you can try and see if the following works

```
>>> for k,v in Emoji.__dict__.items():
...   if "function" in str(v):
...     print(k)
... 
sad
smile
face
__init__
```

Comment: It works but I don't need __init__, other wise my driver will break. (y)